# Activiti framework and teradata compatibility

Tags: integration, teradata, activiti

Recently, I started investigation of activiti framework to integrate it into my current project.
In our project we use teradata database.
So I added activiti dependency and created simple bpmn process for testing purposes.
I tested this process with h2 inmemory database and it worked fine.
But when configured project to use teradata I've got exception on spring boot application startup.

```
Caused by: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: couldn't deduct database type from database product name 'Teradata'
```

I have googled and found only this topic on internet space:

https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-process-services/does-activiti-support-teradata-database/m-p/17587#M287

It seems there is no way to integrate activiti and teradata for now.

So the reason why I am here posting this question is that I just want to make sure there is no way to reach integration between those technologies.

Any suggestions and ideas will be welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the [Teradata JDBC Driver](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver) in your base CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 0):

Activiti is an open source product and can be "adapted" to almost any back end transactional database. Transaction support is a must as any BPMN engine is basically a state machine.
Database access is isolated in the entity layer and specific SQL is managed by the Ibatis ORM.
To integrate a specific database, you will need to modify the entity and ORM layers.
Certainly possible and actually not that much work (typically about 30 hours in my experience), but it is work you have to do and maintain yourself.